# Стоящие впритык блоки не всегда влезают в одну строчку

Tags: html, css

Верстаю адаптивно-резиновую сеточку, опираясь на ширину через vw и высчитывая ширину колонок через calc, потому что 100vw при делении на число колонок иногда даёт бесконечную десятичную дробь (flexbox в моём случае не очень удобен, но это уже совсем другая история, вопрос не про него).

Проблема в том, что при использовании `calc` блоки, которые по идее идеально влезают в одну строчку, на практике таки не влезают. Разверните пример ниже на всю страницу и покрутите ширину окна браузера: последний блок то влезает, то съезжает, как минимум в Firefox.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.item {
  float: left; /* флоат убирает пробелы между элементами */
  width: calc(100vw * 1.0 / 13.0);
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">2</div>
 <div class="item">3</div>
 <div class="item">4</div>
 <div class="item">5</div>
 <div class="item">6</div>
 <div class="item">7</div>
 <div class="item">8</div>
 <div class="item">9</div>
 <div class="item">10</div>
 <div class="item">11</div>
 <div class="item">12</div>
 <div class="item">13</div>
</header>
```

Причём такое поведение не воспроизводится при числе колонок 6 или 12. Воспроизводится при 16, но `calc(100vw / 16.0)` хотя бы можно заменить на `6.25vw`, ибо делится. Здесь я воткнул 13 для наглядности.

Я догадываюсь, что такое происходит из-за ограниченной точности вычислений, но всё-таки — какие есть способы избежать подобного поведения и запихнуть-таки всё в одну строчку и без flexbox? (И без css grid layout, ибо не кроссбраузерно.) Пока на ум приходит что-то вроде `margin-right: -1px` последнему элементу, но костыль какой-то.

Comment: Костыли - наше всё. Всуньте свой `margin-right: -1px;` не стесняясь, такое не стесняются делать даже самые "крутые" верстальщики, ибо по другому - никак(силами html/css), может на js у вас что-то с этим получится

Comment: Если бы CSS работало везде  как надо  и как задумано - javascript программисты лишились бы 80% своей работы.

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100vw / 13.0);
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="item">1</div><div class="item">2</div><div class="item">3</div><div class="item">4</div><div class="item">5</div><div class="item">6</div><div class="item">7</div><div class="item">8</div><div class="item">9</div><div class="item">10</div><div class="item">11</div><div class="item">12</div><div class="item">13</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

вариант с использование `display: table` + `table-layout: fixed`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2em;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
</header>
```